# My WordPress shortcodes are only accepting 'default' values from attribute, not my 'manual' values of attribute. Here are the codes

Tags: php, wordpress, default

These Codes are in my Shortcodes PHP file:

```
function zboom_slider($atts,$content){

    ob_start(); 

    $blockattr = extract(shortcode_atts(array(

        'number' => '2'


        ),'$atts'));

    ?>

    <div class="row-fliud clearfix" id="our-team">
                    <h1>Our Team</h1>

                    <?php $team=new WP_Query(array(

                        'post_type' => 'team-member',
                        'posts_per_page' => $number

                        )); 

                    while($team->have_posts()): $team->the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="span3" id="member1">
                        <a href="#"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                        <span><?php $teamskills=get_the_terms(get_the_id(),'team-skill'); 

                        foreach($teamskills as $teamcat){

                            echo $teamcat->name;

                        }


                        ?></span>
                        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

                    </div>


                <?php endwhile; ?>

                </div>

    <?php $myslider= ob_get_clean();
    return $myslider;

}

add_shortcode('shortslider','zboom_slider');
```

'number' attribute is being used as a variable in 'posts_per_page' value which will define how many posts will show in a page.

**This is what i am using as a shortcode with attribute:**

[shortslider number="3"]

Comment: `),'$atts'));` should be `), $atts));`.

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to find the easiest thing. Thanks  cabrerahector.Solved